# Can we detect memory accesses by a guest OS in Xen?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, kernel, xen

Can we detect every time memory is accessed by an instruction given by a guest OS in Xen?
Or if that is not possible, is there a way to know the memory accesses made by instructions running in Linux?

Comment: Do you need to detect only the accesses to a particular memory area or just all the accesses? If you are interested in a particular memory area only, hardware breakpoints may be helpful (if your hardware supports them), as well as the technique Kmemcheck tool uses: "hiding"/"unhiding" the memory pages and handling the page faults on accesses. It all depends on what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: On the other hand, if you need to get all the memory accesses made by a **given component** of the kernel and you can recompile the Linux kernel with a relatively recent GCC (4.9.x or, better, 5.x), take a look at the implementation of KAsan, that is AddressSanitizer tool for the Linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, @Eugene - I am interested in all memory accesses and want to know which physical address of memory is being accessed by ANY component running on the OS (at run time - I want to call a particular function everytime physical memory is being accessed). If that is not possible then another thing that might solve my problem is to know whenever any virtual addresses get translated to their corresponding physical memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can. The smallest example is [xen-access.c](http://xenbits.xen.org/gitweb/?p=xen.git;a=blob;f=tools/tests/xen-access/xen-access.c;h=cdb8f4e50a30521a735f001f5254d09d5bc2441a;hb=HEAD). There's also [libvmi](http://libvmi.com/), and [libbdvmi](https://github.com/razvan-cojocaru/libbdvmi). The basic idea is to set the pages you're interested in read-only, which will cause a page fault at the first attempt at writing to them, which can in turn result in a vm_event that you can receive in a dom0 (or a similarly privileged domain) userspace application. But, if you want to do this for *all* the guest's pages and *all* writes you'll slow the guest down to a crawl.